# Fast(er) numpy fancy indexing and reduction?

Tags: python, optimization, numpy, scipy, cython

I'm trying to use and accelerate fancy indexing to "join" two arrays and sum over one of results' axis.

Something like this:

```
$ ipython
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: ne, ds = 12, 6
In [3]: i = np.random.randn(ne, ds).astype('float32')
In [4]: t = np.random.randint(0, ds, size=(1e5, ne)).astype('uint8')

In [5]: %timeit i[np.arange(ne), t].sum(-1)
10 loops, best of 3: 44 ms per loop
```

Is there a simple way to accelerate the statement in `In [5]` ? Should I go with OpenMP and something like `scipy.weave` or `Cython`'s `prange` ?

Comment: Another related question is how would I use `pandas` to do the same thing ?

Comment: Numpy is doing that at C speed so you probably won't be able to speed it up much with weave.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`numpy.take` is much faster than fancy indexing for some reason. The only trick is that it treats the array as flat.

```
In [1]: a = np.random.randn(12,6).astype(np.float32)

In [2]: c = np.random.randint(0,6,size=(1e5,12)).astype(np.uint8)

In [3]: r = np.arange(12)

In [4]: %timeit a[r,c].sum(-1)
10 loops, best of 3: 46.7 ms per loop

In [5]: rr, cc = np.broadcast_arrays(r,c)

In [6]: flat_index = rr*a.shape[1] + cc

In [7]: %timeit a.take(flat_index).sum(-1)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.5 ms per loop

In [8]: (a.take(flat_index).sum(-1) == a[r,c].sum(-1)).all()
Out[8]: True
```

I think the only other way you're going to see much of a speed improvement beyond this would be to write a custom kernel for a GPU using something like [PyCUDA](http://documen.tician.de/pycuda/).

Comment: It only treats the array as flat by default, you can still use the `axis` keyword. Ie, `np.take(np.arange(10).reshape((-1,2)), [0], axis=0)` will select the first row.

Comment: @jorgeca: right, but I don't think you can pull individual elements by specifying both row and column like you can with fancy indexing unless you index the flat array.