# Fast numpy fancy indexing

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, slice

My code for slicing a numpy array (via fancy indexing) is very slow. It is currently a bottleneck in program.

```
a.shape
(3218, 6)

ts = time.time(); a[rows][:, cols]; te = time.time(); print('%.8f' % (te-ts));
0.00200009
```

What is the correct numpy call to get an array consisting of the subset of rows 'rows' and columns 'col' of the matrix a? (in fact, I need the transpose of this result)

Comment: `time.time` isn't a great way to measure timing.  Generally, it's better to use `timeit` instead.

Comment: 1. What is your program doing exactly? 2. Use a proper python profiler. I find it quite unlikely that slicing is your bottleneck

Comment: If the slicing is the problem than you could consider using a view instead

Comment: mgilson: I know about timeit, but since this call is deep within a code and I didn't know how to pass in local variable values (`a` in this case). I don't think it's equivalent to `a[rows,cols]` if rows and cols are not consecutive ranges. Right? mbatchkarov: I found this bottleneck by profiling using `cProfile` and `pstats`. My program manipulates large arrays for a genetics application. Thanks both for your feedback.

Comment: I should mention I only need the sub-array for reading, not writing. So I'll look into a view. thx

Comment: Oren - If you use `@mgilson` style mentions it will send a notification to the user (one per comment).

Comment: @WoLpH -- Don't slices return a view already?

Comment: What are `rows` and `cols` in this case?

Comment: @mgilson: I remember having issues with that in some cases (4 years ago though), might not apply anymore. The manual says the following `For all cases of index arrays, what is returned is a copy of the original data, not a view as one gets for slices` http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html?highlight=slice#index-arrays

Comment: @Wolph It is still true for [Numpy 1.15](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html): _Advanced indexing always returns a copy of the data (contrast with basic slicing that returns a view)_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get some speed up if you slice using fancy indexing and broadcasting:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np

def slice_1(a, rs, cs) :
    return a[rs][:, cs]

def slice_2(a, rs, cs) :
    return a[rs[:, None], cs]

>>> rows, cols = 3218, 6
>>> rs = np.unique(np.random.randint(0, rows, size=(rows//2,)))
>>> cs = np.unique(np.random.randint(0, cols, size=(cols//2,)))
>>> a = np.random.rand(rows, cols)
>>> import timeit
>>> print timeit.timeit('slice_1(a, rs, cs)',
                        'from __main__ import slice_1, a, rs, cs',
                        number=1000)
0.24083110865
>>> print timeit.timeit('slice_2(a, rs, cs)',
                        'from __main__ import slice_2, a, rs, cs',
                        number=1000)
0.206566124519
```

If you think in term of percentages, doing something 15% faster is always good, but in my system, for the size of your array, this is taking 40 us less to do the slicing, and it is hard to believe that an operation taking 240 us will be your bottleneck.

Comment: Turns out I have a 3218x1415 array, not 3218x6. I am extracting only a few columns and lots of rows. The code above reveals that slice_1 call time is 0.08 sec, slice_2 time 0.0004 sec. Maybe that's what I need!

Answer (score 22):

Let my try to summarize the excellent answers by Jaime and TheodrosZelleke and mix in some comments.

1. [Advanced (fancy) indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) always returns a copy, never a view.
2. `a[rows][:,cols]` implies *two* fancy indexing operations, so an intermediate copy `a[rows]` is created and discarded. Handy and readable, but not very efficient. Moreover beware that `[:,cols]` usually generates a Fortran contiguous copy from a C-cont. source.
3. `a[rows.reshape(-1,1),cols]` is a single advanced indexing expression basing on the fact that `rows.reshape(-1,1)` and `cols` are [broadcast](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to the shape of the intended result.
4. A common experience is that indexing in a flattened array can be more efficient than fancy indexing, so another approach is

   ```
   indx = rows.reshape(-1,1)*a.shape[1] + cols
   a.take(indx)
   ```

or

```
    a.take(indx.flat).reshape(rows.size,cols.size)
```

5. Efficiency will depend on memory access patterns and whether the starting array is C-countinous or Fortran continuous, so experimentation is needed.
6. Use fancy indexing only if really needed: [basic slicing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#slicing-and-striding) `a[rstart:rstop:rstep, cstart:cstop:cstep]` returns a view (although not continuous) and should be faster!

Answer (score 18):

To my surprise this, kind of lenghty expression, which calculates first linear 1D-indices, is more than **50%** faster than the consecutive array indexing presented in the question:

```
(a.ravel()[(
   cols + (rows * a.shape[1]).reshape((-1,1))
   ).ravel()]).reshape(rows.size, cols.size)
```

**UPDATE:** OP updated the description of the shape of the initial array. With the updated size the speedup is now above **99%**:

```
In [93]: a = np.random.randn(3218, 1415)

In [94]: rows = np.random.randint(a.shape[0], size=2000)

In [95]: cols = np.random.randint(a.shape[1], size=6)

In [96]: timeit a[rows][:, cols]
10 loops, best of 3: 186 ms per loop

In [97]: timeit (a.ravel()[(cols + (rows * a.shape[1]).reshape((-1,1))).ravel()]).reshape(rows.size, cols.size)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.56 ms per loop
```

**INITAL ANSWER:**
Here is the transcript:

```
In [79]: a = np.random.randn(3218, 6)
In [80]: a.shape
Out[80]: (3218, 6)

In [81]: rows = np.random.randint(a.shape[0], size=2000)
In [82]: cols = np.array([1,3,4,5])
```

Time method 1:

```
In [83]: timeit a[rows][:, cols]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.26 ms per loop
```

Time method 2:

```
In [84]: timeit (a.ravel()[(cols + (rows * a.shape[1]).reshape((-1,1))).ravel()]).reshape(rows.size, cols.size)
1000 loops, best of 3: 568 us per loop
```

Check that results are actually the same:

```
In [85]: result1 = a[rows][:, cols]
In [86]: result2 = (a.ravel()[(cols + (rows * a.shape[1]).reshape((-1,1))).ravel()]).reshape(rows.size, cols.size)

In [87]: np.sum(result1 - result2)
Out[87]: 0.0
```

Comment: It is also about twice as fast as the more standard answer I provided, for the new requirement of the OP. Nice!

Comment: Not to say that such tricks can't speed things up (at least in specific cases), but all of this heavily relies on the fact that the input array is C-Contiguous.

Comment: No surprise: see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11813040/1499402) to a related question.

Answer (score 1):

Using `np.ix_` you can a similar speed to ravel/reshape, but with code that is more clear:

```
a = np.random.randn(3218, 1415)
rows = np.random.randint(a.shape[0], size=2000)
cols = np.random.randint(a.shape[1], size=6)
a = np.random.randn(3218, 1415)
rows = np.random.randint(a.shape[0], size=2000)
cols = np.random.randint(a.shape[1], size=6)

%timeit (a.ravel()[(cols + (rows * a.shape[1]).reshape((-1,1))).ravel()]).reshape(rows.size, cols.size)
#101 µs ± 2.36 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)


%timeit ix_ = np.ix_(rows, cols); a[ix_]
#135 µs ± 7.47 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

ix_ = np.ix_(rows, cols)
result1 = a[ix_]
result2 = (a.ravel()[(cols + (rows * a.shape[1]).reshape((-1,1))).ravel()]).reshape(rows.size, cols.size)
​
np.sum(result1 - result2)
0.0
```